# How to switch an AccordionContainer on click?

Tags: javascript, widget, onclick, dojo

I have an app that uses a `dijit.layout.AccordionContainer` with two child containers.

When the map is loaded, one of the containers is open by default. I would like the default container to close and the second container to open when a button is clicked. Any idea how to do this?

I have tried using the `selectChild()` method but must be doing it wrong or am I completely off base?

EDIT My HTML is:

```
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" region="left" splitter="true">
   <div dojotype="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">
      <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Table of Contents">
           <div id="tocDiv"></div>
      </div>
      <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Search Results" id="tab2">
           <div id="datagrid">
                <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-id="grid"  id="grid" data-dojo-props="rowsPerPage:'5', rowSelector:'20px'">
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                            <th field="Parcel Identification Number" width="25%">Parcel ID/th>
                            <th field="Site Address" width="30%"> Address </th>
                         </tr>
                     </thead>
                 </table>
             </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where I am trying to open "tab2" on click via a function I have created for some other things I need to happen on click

JS:

```
function doFind() {             
     //Set the search text to the value in the box
     findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("parcel").value;
     grid.showMessage("Loading..."); //Shows the Loading Message until search results are returned.
     findTask.execute(findParams,showResults);
}
```

Comment: How are you creating your widgets? How are you calling `selectChild()`? What version of Dojo? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/29/) seems to do what you are asking just fine.

Comment: I have edited my question to show my code. I have removed my selectChild() reference since I don't seem to be doing it right.

Comment: That fiddle did the trick. Thanks for the help. If you make your comment an answer I will mark it as answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are on the right track trying to using the `AccordionContainer#selectChild` method. This should be easy to handle by setting your Button's `onClick` handler as follows:

```
onClick: function(){
    var container = dijit.byId("container");
    container.selectChild("pane2", true); 
}
```

Where `"pane2`" is the id of the ContentPane that you want to open on button click, and `true` indicates that you want the opening of the pane to be animated. You can see an example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/29/).